# Nested CSS errors introducing Tailwind to a Next.js/React app

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

New to Next.js/React here. I followed the [Tailwind CSS for Next.js tutorial](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs) and added Tailwind to my project like so:

```
npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
npx tailwindcss init -p
```

Then, per those instructions, modified the generated `tailwind.config.js` like so:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,jsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,jsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

and `globals.css` like so:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

...rest of my CSS styles are down here (there are many)
```

When I started up the dev server (`npm run dev`) I got errors complaining about it detecting nested CSS which led me to eventually find [this article on fixing CSS nesting in Tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#nesting).

So I updated `postcss.config.js` to look like:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    'postcss-import': {},
    'tailwindcss/nesting': {},
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  }
}
```

And now I am seeing these errors:

```
wait  - compiling...
wait  - compiling /404 (client and server)...
warn  - ./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/css-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[8].use[1]!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[8].use[2]!./styles/globals.css
Warning

(42:5) Nested CSS was detected, but CSS nesting has not been configured correctly.
Please enable a CSS nesting plugin *before* Tailwind in your configuration.
See how here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#nesting
warn  - ./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/css-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[8].use[1]!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[8].use[2]!./styles/globals.css
Warning

(42:5) Nested CSS was detected, but CSS nesting has not been configured correctly.
Please enable a CSS nesting plugin *before* Tailwind in your configuration.
See how here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#nesting
warn  - ./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/css-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[8].use[1]!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[8].use[2]!./styles/globals.css
Warning

(42:5) Nested CSS was detected, but CSS nesting has not been configured correctly.
Please enable a CSS nesting plugin *before* Tailwind in your configuration.
See how here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#nesting
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Skipped not serializable cache item 'Compilation/modules|/Users/myuser/workspace/myapp/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/css-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[8].use[1]!/Users/myuser/workspace/myapp/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[8].use[2]!/Users/myuser/workspace/myapp/styles/globals.css': No serializer registered for Warning
<w> while serializing webpack/lib/cache/PackFileCacheStrategy.PackContentItems -> webpack/lib/NormalModule -> Array { 1 items } -> webpack/lib/ModuleWarning -> Warning
```

**What is going on here, why am I seeing these errors/warnings and how can I fix them?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleared up the nested CSS violations in my `global.css` file and Tailwind is now working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you've missed the last step. Step-4. Run the following command

```
npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch
```

step 1

```
npm install -D tailwindcss
npx tailwindcss init
```

step 2

```
Add the paths to all of your template files in your tailwind.config.js file.

module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

step 3

```
Add the @tailwind directives for each of Tailwind’s layers to your main CSS file

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

step 4

```
Start the Tailwind CLI build process

npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch
```

Comment: Thanks @Marat but I don't think this is it. I don't even have a `src/input.css`. Where do you see this step mentioned in the docs?

Comment: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation

Comment: Check this out. I installed tailwind just yesterday and everything works fine

Comment: I didn't have input.css too. But it seems like it is necessary to run this command. I think it won't work otherwise

Comment: When I run that command it complains the `src/input.css` does not exist. Are you using Next.js & React as well?

Comment: Sorry for misleading you. Yes you are right. I was using create-react-app that's probably why everything worked out of the box.